# C# static constructor in instance class -- Pros & Contras

Tags: c#, static

I use static constructor in instance class to make this class initialization with some Resource constants. My more experience colleague remark, that it is bad C# style as any static in code. More reliable with his opinion is external public readonly class for this.

However, VisualStudio C# provide run of internal static constructor at first address to common resource, vs external class, which i should call from higher program level. Isn't it a source for additional errors? Am i correct with this logic?

Comment: "it is bad C# style as **any static in code**" [I have some bad news for your colleague...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide some code so we could look/discuss around it?

Comment: Static is not bad C# style. There are a great many applications for it in which it is the preferred method. Tell your colleague that in shutting himself off to an entire major feature of the language he is gimping himself as a developer.

Comment: Exactly one of the following statements is true, though we don't know which: (1) We have misunderstood you.  (2) You have misunderstood your colleague.  (3) Your colleague doesn't know what he's talking about, and you shouldn't listen to him. - "Never make anything static" is as useless a decree as "always make everything static".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you ask is about coding style. Some prefer using static, some prefer to avoid it.

Static can be very helpfull and there are a few features which rely on static. For instance Main, Class Extension, Singleton pattern.

I was greatly using static for my own code because it makes a lot of things easy (you don't have to worry about building the shared stuff). However, when I started doing unit testing I felt more and more unconfortable with it. Static data by definition will be created once and shared which means that for unit tests this data will be shared by the tests. It makes tests independancy much more difficult, forcing you to reset manually everything in your Setup/Teardown methods.

In a few words, for the purpose of unit testing and modularity, I would discourage you from using static constructor for data which isn't immutable (or at least that you use as immutable -> read only access). Immutable data is not an issue as it won't be altered while the program (or the tests) run and you can always be confident about it's value.

Again this is some kind of coding style and some people will disagree and that's fine (as long as they know why they prefer another style)

Comment: Thanks Bruno! Indeed, behind of this discussion more than "bad stile smell", but the fact: static data are open for other piece of the project, which could lead to the information corruption. You're right: manual reset forcing is a serious headache. However, there are no way, beyond manual restart to get another set of external resources, isn't it?
Sure, some static methods (Program Main, some string methods etc) unavoidable. This is rather about balance between C# code complexity, and data protection.

Comment: One more case I faced yesterday is inline with this post: I left static constructor in instance class; it read input Excel file and setup environment information at first address to the target class. Indeed it is quite convenient, however yesterday I included this class in Unit Test, and got **System.TypeInitializationException**. Any sugestion @Bruno Belmondo?

Comment: Feels like you may be missing one dll in your unit test. Try checking that all required dlls are in the output directory of your unit test project and if not try adding an explicit reference.

Comment: Dear Bruno, after long time with the instance class singleton initialization from superior class, I returned to static constructor as a singleton - now from Property resx item, instead of previously used Excel. It works fine: much faster and safer, than Microsoft.Interop.Excel.dll, it allows Unit Tests; it keep everything in one module, i.e. more readable.
What your experience say about it?

Comment: Sorry but I did not have this precise use case so I won't be able to tell you much. However I feel you are know understanding the reason of your choices and are capable of arguing why you made this choice. THis probably mean you are also able to evaluate in the future how it is doing and if any change has to be done.